# Python_Calculate Opening and Closing Loan Balance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to compute Opeaning and Closing Balance of Loan by using Python (loop). I am new in Python and therefore, I have some difficulties in this. By doing some google search I do write the following code:

```
 from __future__ import print_function
 import numpy as np

 amount = 20000
 int_rate = 0.012
 term = 5
 nper = 12
 mtly_pmt = 100

 fmt = 'year {0:2d} {1:8.2f} {2:8.2f}'

 for y in range(0, term + 1):
     print(fmt.format(
             y,
             np.fv(int_rate/nper, y*nper, mtly_pmt, -amount),
             np.fv(int_rate/nper, y*nper, mtly_pmt, -amount)
           )
     )
```

My result is like following:

```
 year  0 20000.00 20000.00
 year  1 19034.70 19034.70
 year  2 18057.76 18057.76
 year  3 17069.02 17069.02
 year  4 16068.36 16068.36
 year  5 15055.62 15055.62
```

However, it should be like that:

```
 Year      Opening       Closing
    0      20000         19034.70
    1      19034.70      18057.76
    2      18057.76      17069.02
    3      17069.20      16068.36
    4      16068.36      15055.62
```

I would really appreciate it if you could help me to get this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just printing the same value two times. That was the problem. Instead, you have to save the previous amount and then use it to calculate the next value.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

amount = 20000
int_rate = 0.012
term = 5
nper = 12
mtly_pmt = 100

fmt = '{0:4d} {1:10.2f} {2:10.2f}'
print("{:6} {:10} {:10}".format('Year','Opening','Closing'))

for y in range(0,term):    
    opening = amount
    closing = np.fv(int_rate/nper, nper, mtly_pmt, -amount)  
    amount = closing    
    print(fmt.format(y,opening,closing))
```

Comment: Yes, it works. However, I need to give name to columns. Can I do it in print()?

Comment: Yes, you can although you need to format it properly. I will edit the code for that

Comment: Great. Thanks for that